# Using connect-pg-simple with Heroku PostgreSQL tries to connect without SSL

Tags: connection-pooling, pg, node-postgres

pGetting this when trying to connect to a Heroku-hosted PostgreSQL database.

> error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "IP_ADDRESS", user "USER",
> database "DBNAME", SSL off

Here's my code...

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import pg from 'pg'
import session from 'express-session'
import ConnectPgSimple from 'connect-pg-simple'

const result = dotenv.config()
const { Client, native } = pg

const pgNativePool = new native.Pool({
  max: 10, // default
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
})

// This is the block of code causing the error
const pgSession = new ConnectPgSimple(session);
const store = new pgSession({
  pool: pgNativePool,
  tableName: 'sessions'
})

export default {
  query: (sql, params) => pgNativePool.query(sql, params),
  store // used by express-session
}
```

I am using connect-pg-simple to store sessions in the database. If I cut that part out, the errors do not occur. I would have thought connect-pg-simple would be reusing existing connections in native.Pool.

Any thoughts as to why it would try to reconnect without SSL?

Comment: You're getting error connecting to the postgres in heroku from your local dev or from heroku?

Comment: Getting the error locally and from Heroku. I think Heroku just started enforcing SSL yesterday evening. My site was getting tons of errors so I tried to reproduce it locally by trying to connect to their PostgreSQL database. Sure enough...

Answer (score 0):

if you install Heroku Postgress addon, they should attach environment variable to your application having postgresql connection string in it.

Their official example is this:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js

So, i think this code should work:

```
import { Pool, Client } from 'pg';
const pool = new Pool({
  max: 10,
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: true
  }
});

export default {
  query: (sql, params) => pool.query(sql, params)
};
```

Comment: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "IP_ADDRESS", user "USER", database "DBNAME", SSL off

Comment: probably password is wrong, or ip address you use is wrong - heroku probably doesn't allows remote access to free tier postgres databases

Comment: The issue was that I left out the name of the pool property so I guess connect-pg-simple was opening its own non-SSL connection.

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you're working in your local development, you need to connect using `connectionString`.

However, if you're deploying to heroku, then heroku will provide the connectionString via `process.env.DATABASE_URL`

You may try the following code and see if it works.

```
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const connectionString = `postgresql://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_DATABASE}`;
const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: isProduction ? process.env.DATABASE_URL : connectionString,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});
```

Comment: I have a .env file with DATABASE_URL defined (matching the one on Heroku) loaded via dotenv.

Comment: try remove the `?sslmode=require` at the back of the string.

else you should provide your cert like the following link:
https://node-postgres.com/features/ssl

Answer (score 0):

I left out the pool property name when defining the pgSession (corrected above).